# I have my /home in a separate drive, but it keeps unmounting after about 2 days of uptime. What should I do to fix it?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, home-directory

My /home folder is mounted in a separate ssd to have more room and my main system files are in `/dev/sda1`. Here's the `df -h` list that is relevant:

```
/dev/sdb1       458G  129G  306G  30% /home
```

It will run fine on boot but after a few days of being up, the disk will just unmount itself and send me to an infinite lock screen. I usually just reboot and its fine. I have also manually re-mounted the drive and that also works. But it's more time consuming than just rebooting. I used to run manjaro and this was never an issue with that.

===========================Edit=======================================

The `/home` is on a SATAIII drive and is not a USB or other removable media.

The OS is Linux Mint with Gnome.

Comment: There should be a reason for the separate SSD being unmounted somewhere within `/var/log/syslog`. Is the second SSD connected via USB or as some form of removable media? 

Comment: What OS are you using now?

Comment: Is your /home on an external USB3 drive? Is it connected to a USB3 port? What brand drive? What size? Does it have it's own external AC adapter? If so, edit your question and show me `lsusb` and `lsusb -tv`.

Comment: My /home is on a second sata III ssd. Not removable media

Comment: It may be a loose contact. Reseat the secondary drive if this is a laptop. Make sure the SATA cable is securely plugged in at both ends. If it is a bad cable, change the cable.

Comment: And Mint is off-topic here.